# Decreasing the compilation time when using shapeless HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

Scala 2.12.6, Shapeless 2.3.3.

I have a lot of large models (case classes) which are quite deep. I use shapeless to help use/manipulate these models and also use libraries like circe which make heavy use of shapeless.

This has caused my compilation time to increase massively during the `phase typer` part of scalac.

Based on a bit of Googling, it appears that shapeless is the culprit, but I can't seem to find any concrete tips on how I can improve this.

It was suggested that because I am resolving the HList implicits multiple times (because of the multiple libraries) for the same models, that I should "cache them" - however I'm not sure how to figure out exactly what to cache.

Given something like:

```scala
case class MyModel(value: String) extends AnyVal
case class MyOtherModel(value: Int) extends AnyVal
case class MyRootModel(myModel: MyModel, myOtherModel: MyOtherModel)
```

What should I be caching for `MyModel`/`MyOtherModel` and `MyRootModel`?

Answer (score 11):

You can cache Shapeless's `LabelledGeneric` instances like this:

```
import shapeless.{LabelledGeneric, the}

case class MyModel(value: String) extends AnyVal
case class MyOtherModel(value: Int) extends AnyVal
case class MyRootModel(myModel: MyModel, myOtherModel: MyOtherModel)

object MyModel {
  implicit val generic = the[LabelledGeneric[MyModel]]
}

object MyOtherModel {
  implicit val generic = the[LabelledGeneric[MyOtherModel]]
}

object MyRootModel {
  implicit val generic = the[LabelledGeneric[MyRootModel]]
}
```

You should of course see if this improves compilation times in your own project, but as a quick benchmark we can set up a test that resolves the `LabelledGeneric` repeatedly (a thousand times in this case):

```
object Test {
  def foo0 = {
    LabelledGeneric[MyRootModel]
    LabelledGeneric[MyRootModel]
    // repeat 98 more times...
  }
  def foo1 = {
    LabelledGeneric[MyRootModel]
    LabelledGeneric[MyRootModel]
    // repeat 98 more times...
  }
  // and so on through foo9 
}
```

(Note that we have to split up the invocations because if we just dumped a thousand of them in a row in a single method the macro-generated code would exceed the JVM's method size limits when we comment out the instance caching to compare.)

On my machine a `Test.scala` file containing `Test`, the case class definitions, and the cached instances compiles in about 3 seconds. If we comment out the `generic` definitions, it takes over 12 seconds. This is of course pretty unscientific, but it's encouraging.

Note that in general it's not a good idea to have `implicit` definitions without a type annotation, and you can avoid doing that for the cached instances by writing something like this:

```
import shapeless.{LabelledGeneric, TypeOf, cachedImplicit}

case class MyModel(value: String) extends AnyVal
case class MyOtherModel(value: Int) extends AnyVal
case class MyRootModel(myModel: MyModel, myOtherModel: MyOtherModel)

object MyModel {
  implicit val generic: TypeOf.`LabelledGeneric[MyModel]`.type = cachedImplicit
}

object MyOtherModel {
  implicit val generic: TypeOf.`LabelledGeneric[MyOtherModel]`.type = cachedImplicit
}

object MyRootModel {
  implicit val generic: TypeOf.`LabelledGeneric[MyRootModel]`.type = cachedImplicit
}
```

`TypeOf` is some weird magic, though, and to be honest when I've needed something like this I've just used the `the` approach.

As a footnote, since you mention circe specifically, you might want to give [circe-derivation](https://github.com/circe/circe-derivation) a try. It works as a drop-in replacement for much of the functionality of circe-generic, but isn't built on Shapeless and compiles much more quickly.

Comment: On second thought this is all weird magic and you should probably use the `TypeOf` approach.

Comment: I'm assuming I need to cache the shapeless bits that the libraries are using. `LabelledGeneric` is a good guess for circe, but what about the other libraries, what if they are using something like `Generic.Aux`?

Comment: `LabelledGeneric` extends `Generic`, so this approach will work in that case as well (as you can confirm by changing the example above to resolve `Generic` repeatedly). I guess some other library could use the `DefaultSymbolicLabelling` directly, but apart from some of the circe-generic-extras stuff I'm not sure I've seen that.

Comment: What did you mean by `LabelledGeneric` extends `Generic`?...I can't see this on the class hierarchy

Comment: Oh, you're right. Then yeah, you might want to do the same thing as above for `Generic`, if you're sure that some library you're using requires these.